# Firefox 29 messed up everything: How to return to the old style?

Tags: firefox

I accepted to update software as usual in my Ubuntu machine, but without a warning my Firefox got messed up.

- Icons are now small, have no text and the option to put it back is gone. It used to be `right click > customize > show icons and text`
- Lots of icons are now tied together. Wtf?? Bookmarks is tied to favorites, the reload and back buttons are tied to the address bar, the forward button is smaller and sometimes it's hidden, etc.
- The tabs look weird, not sure why.

I installed Classic Theme Restorer but everything looks the same.

Halp!

Comment: You can’t. _padding to min comment length_

Comment: Dis you use a clean profile when you tried [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/)?

Comment: Classic theme restorer works to a point, but it's just not the same.

Answer (score 0):

go to **https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/** and download and install an older version. Then go into the options and turn off auto update.

Comment: While that might still be ok now, I wouldn't recommend that for long. Old versions won't get security fixes.